# C# DateTime Not Formatting Correctly to String

Tags: c#

I am trying to get the created date and time of a particular file and then format it from `4/9/2016 to 040916`. I end up with the result of `56DD16`.  I am not entirely sure where this value is coming from.  I have used this method to format dates before without any problem.  The code is below:

```
FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(Path.Combine(r.getCompanyFilesLocation(), r.getNyseFileName()));
DateTime dateCreated = fi.CreationTime;
string archiveFileName = dateCreated.ToString("mmDDyy");
```

Comment: MSDN doc: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using incorrect format string,`mm` Represent the `Minute` and there is nothing for `DD`, `dd` stands for `day`. so Change your formatString as `MMddyy`. to get the expected output. [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) you can find more formatting options

```
string archiveFileName = dateCreated.ToString("MMddyy");
```

Answer (score 2):

`.ToString("mmDDyy")` is incorrect. The format should be `.ToString("MMddyy")`

You can always review the [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Answer (score 0):

You were using wrong format. Use this one and you will get the exact same output you required:

```
DateTime dateCreated = fi.CreationTime;
        string archiveFileName = dateCreated.ToString("MMddyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```